# vim delete all lines that contain X or more words

Tags: vim

I am looking for a vim command that will match and remove all lines that contain 4 or more words, where words are separated by a delimiter in this case a whitespace character.

Before

> one two three four five
>
> one two three four
>
> one two three

After

> one two three

Answer (score 4):

Awk to the rescue!

```
awk 'NF < 4' foo.txt > output.txt
```

Using Vim's filter, `:!`, command (See `:h :range!`):

```
:%!awk 'NF < 4'
```

Or pure Vim with `:global` command and `:delete` (See `:h :g` & `:h :d`):

```
:g/\s.*\s.*\s/d_
```

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\v(\w+ \w+ \w+)\zs.*//g

\v ................. very magic (avoids backslashing everything)
(\w+ \w+ \w+) ...... a group of three words
\zs.* .............. starts considering what that comes after
```